# Is opencv imread able to load huge PGM files? Are there alternatives?

Tags: c++, image, opencv, memory

I have a 10GB PGM file and when I try to use cv::imread to load it, I get the following message:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
```

Which is curious since this image was created with opencv imwrite. Is it expected? I did not find in the docs anything mentioning any limitation. Is there an alternative to this method?

The error happens on a Linux box with 64GB RAM, most of it free. Just in case anyone might want to check, below is the program I wrote.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

int main(int argc, char* args[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    cv::Mat img = cv::imread(args[1], cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
    if (img.data == 0)
    {
        return 2;
    }

    std::cout << img.rows << " - " << img.cols;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For some reason, the program was unable to allocate enough memory to complete the operation.  You could be running out of memory or swap space, or the OS could be limiting the amount of memory a single process can allocate (see the `ulimit` command, if you're on a Unix-like OS).

Comment: The command `ulimit -a | grep memory` yelds unlimited max memory size and virtual memory. The machine that runs that code has 64GB RAM, most of it currently unused.

Comment: I ended up digging into the code and it seems to be an OpenCV limitation. I opened [an issue with a patch](http://code.opencv.org/issues/3258). Let's see how they handle this.